# zsh terminal not works correctly on mac

Tags: macos, zsh

I just installed `zsh` on my mac, but get not `~` but `MBP%` on terminal after user name

[image]

Comment: Not on-topic for SO, but you should feel free to edit the prompt via http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion

Comment: `zsh` is working fine; you just have a different prompt than you want.